# Template function that accepts only heirs of some class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

In C++, say that I have some class `mom`. I know that I can make a template function that accepts any class, like:

```
template <class T> void Iacceptanything(T x)
{
  // Do something
}
```

Now, this works nice, but I would like to make a more restrict template class, something that accepts as `T` any type that inherits from class `mom`. I thought about making the function accept `mom` as only argument type, but in that function I need to do build a template object with the argument, therefore I need its type to be preserved (i.e., my object shouldn't be "pruned down" to only its being an heir of `mom`).

What I would need is something like:

```
template <class T:mom> void Iacceptonlysonsofmom(T x)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: You can use `std::enable_if` or `static_assert()` for this, but I would suggest not restricting the template argument; if you use some functionality dependent on `mom` then the template will just fail to instantiate with other objects (unless they provide a compatible interface -- and if they do then why should it make any difference to you?), but if you don't there is no reason to restrict it to only work on `mom` objects.

Answer (score 5):

Use `std::enable_if` and `std::is_base_of`.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

class Base { };
class Derived : public Base { };
class NotDerived { };

// If the return type of foo() is not void, add where indicated.
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value /*, some_type*/>::type
foo(T) {
    std::cout << "Derived from Base." << std::endl;
}

// If the return type of foo() is not void, add where indicated.
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value /*, some_type*/>::type
foo(T) {
    std::cout << "Not derived from Base." << std::endl;
}

int
main() {
    Derived d;
    NotDerived nd;

    foo(d);
    foo(nd);
}
```

Comment: You can drop the explicit 2nd parameter for `std::enable_if` since it defaults to `void`

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested you can use `enable_if` and [SFINAE (Substition Failure Is Not An Error)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) but it can be problematic. It can be fragile across compilers, may cause problems with ODR if not done properly, can cause conflicts with  functions pulled in from other scopes (ADL), and may not be the best option.

You do have a couple of alternative options which are less fickle and may make your code easier to understand and maintain. One option (as mentioned in comments) is to use [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) and [`is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of). This is by far (IMHO) the easiest solution for what you are trying to accomplish. This approach allows you to maintain a single implementation of the function and force a compile time failure if the type is not the base `Mom` or derived from it.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Mom { };
struct Child : Mom { };
struct Uncle { };

template <typename T>
void AcceptOnlyMomAndChildren(T)
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Mom, T>::value, "Not derived from Base.");
}

int main()
{
    Child child;
    Uncle uncle;

    AcceptOnlyMomAndChildren(child);
    AcceptOnlyMomAndChildren(uncle);    //  Fails
}
```

If you need to provide multiple functions that can handle types that are not derived from a particular base class using tag dispatching may make more sense. This is far less fickle across compilers and must easier on the eyes. It can also be easily expanded if you ever need to provide special handling for a type derived from `mom` (in your example).

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct Mom { };
struct Child : Mom { };
struct Uncle { };

template <typename T>
void Func(T&, std::true_type)
{
    std::cout << "Derived from Base." << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void Func(T&, std::false_type)
{
    std::cout << "Not derived from Base." << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void Func(T& arg)
{
    Func(
        arg,
        typename std::conditional<
            std::is_base_of<Mom, T>::value,
            std::true_type, std::false_type>::type());
}


int main()
{
    Child child;
    Uncle uncle;

    Func(child);
    Func(uncle);
}
```

In the above example [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) is used to specify the type of an additional argument determine which implementation of `Func` is called. You can substitute it with your own type traits scheme to support additional implementations if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::enable_if` and `std::is_base_of` like this:

```
template <typename T, typename = enable_if<is_base_of<mom, T>::value>::type>
void Iacceptonlysonsofmom(T x)
{
}
```

If you cannot use `C++11`, you can achieve the same using Boost's `enable_if_c` and `is_base_of`. In the above code, you will need to replace `enable_if` with `enable_if_c` and ensure that you use the appropriate namespaces.